# Lines Between Datapoints of different columns

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have these example-data saved in test.txt

```
1   2
2   3
3   5
4   5
5   6
```

I can easily plot them by

```
plot "test.txt" u 0:1,"" u 0:2
```

the result is
[just the data plotted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Auv4G.png)

but what i want is some lines between the datapoints to illustrate the difference and which points belong to the same x-value. (photoshopped scribble below)

[same image with lines between datapoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWqEg.png)

Is there any way i could achieve this with gnuplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the vectors style

```
plot "test.txt" u 0:1,"" u 0:2, "" u 0:1:(0):($2-$1) with vectors nohead
```

The vectors style expects 4 values which are the x and y coordinates, the x change (0 in this case), and the y change (the difference between your 2 columns).  The nohead option removes the arrow head that is normally added.

You can style the vector using most line style specifications, and if necessary, can adjust coordinates to add some spacing.  For example, setting the lines black and padding the lines by 0.1 in both directions by

```
plot "test.txt" u 0:1, "" u 0:2, "" u 0:($1+0.1):(0):($2-$1-0.2) with vectors nohead lc "black"
```

gives

[image]

I manually set ranges with `set xrange` and `set yrange` to match your images, as mine was using slightly different defaults.

See `help vectors` for more information on the vectors style.